# How do I create a transparent window with red border?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a software that records the screen when a key is pressed. In order to indicate that the program is now recording, I want to put a red border around the outside of the screen. I'm having trouble getting it to work, here is my attempt so far:

```
public Main() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    frame.setSize((int)ss.getWidth(), (int)ss.getHeight());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.createBufferStrategy(3);

    BufferStrategy bs = frame.getBufferStrategy();

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth()-1, frame.getHeight()-1);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

It seems like setting the background transparent makes the graphics object not able to draw onto the jframe, and setting the background of the graphics object to transparent only leaves a white background with a red border, rather than transparent. I'm completely stuck on this one at the moment so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really draw on a component that way, you would need to override `paintComponent(g)` to do that.

You can simply add a border object:

```
        ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 10));
```

Comment: Thank you. I was planning on drawing a small icon in the corner aswell. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The typical way to do it is to create an Icon (see the ImageIcon class for instance), add it into a JLabel and add the JLabel where you want

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following code achieves what you want. Notes after the code.

```java
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Recorder implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        if (contentPane instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent jCmpt = (JComponent) contentPane;
            jCmpt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 5, true));
        }
        frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Start here
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Recorder());
    }
}
```

- `setExtendedState()` maximizes the `JFrame` so that it takes up the entire screen.
- `setUndecorated()` removes the title bar and the border of the `JFrame`.
- `setBackground()` makes the `JFrame` transparent.
- `setLocationRelativeTo()` is optional since the `JFrame` is maximized.
- Finally I set a thick, red, rounded border around the content pane of the `JFrame`.

Note that you can close the `JFrame` by pressing Alt+F4 keys on the computer keyboard.

Optionally, you can also add the following:

```java
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```